# PrintJobEventListener is not generating event print completed or print failed

Tags: java

I am using java api of print service which provides PrintJobEventListner to get events of job completed, print progress, print fail etc. Here is my code snippet. Method which will get pdf to be printed, get the object of PrintService and add class "PrinterEventListner " which is implementing PrintJobEventListner .

```
    public void createPrintJob() throws PrintException, IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            DocFlavor psFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
            PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            aset.add(new Copies(2));
            aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
            aset.add(Sides.TWO_SIDED_LONG_EDGE);
            aset.add(Finishings.STAPLE);
    PrintService pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocPrintJob pj = pservices.createPrintJob();
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                        "/path/file.pdf");
    PrinterEventListner eventListner = new PrinterEventListner();
    Doc doc;
                pj.addPrintJobListener(eventListner);   
              doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, psFlavor, null);
    System.out.println("The printerName: " + pservices.getName());
                pj.print(doc, aset);
    } catch (IOException e) {

                System.err.println(e);
            } catch (PrintException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
```

Here is my PrinterEventListner class :

```
    public class PrinterEventListner implements PrintJobListener {
        boolean completed;
        public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();    
            System.out.println("Printing on progress");
        }
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                signalCompletion();
            System.out.println("Printing Completed");
        }
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
            System.out.println("Printing Failed");
        }
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
           signalCompletion();
            System.out.println("Printing cancelled");
        }
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
            System.out.println("No more events on Printing");
        }
        public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
            System.out.println("PrintJob Needs Attention");
        }
        private void signalCompletion() {
            synchronized (PrinterEventListner.this) {
                completed = true;
                PrinterEventListner.this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        public synchronized void waitForJobCompletion() {
            try {
                while (!completed) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
```

while executing the code I am getting events only for printDataTransferCompleted() and printJobNoMoreEvents(). printJobCompleted()/printJobFailed() doesnot seems to be working. I searched in many different forum with same issue but no solution. Does anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Same issue, just printDataTransferCompleted() working for me.